# why hashMap.toSortedMap returns one entry less

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, sortedmap

having a hasMap with four entries, after the toSortedMap the result map has only three entries.

```
var uuidToConfigMap = HashMap<UUID, Config>()
```

the config type:

```
data class Config (

    val test: String,

    val type: Int,  
    val priority: Int

) {
    override fun toString() : String {
        return "type:$type, priority:$priority"+",  test:"+test
    }
}
```

the data and sort code, uuidToConfigMap has four entries:

```
var uuidToConfigMap = HashMap<UUID, Config>()

uuidToConfigMap[UUID.randomUUID()
] = Config(“xxx”, 1000, 1)

uuidToConfigMap[UUID.randomUUID()
] = Config(“yyy”, 1000, 1)

uuidToConfigMap[UUID.randomUUID()
] = Config(“video”, 100, 2)

uuidToConfigMap[UUID.randomUUID()
] = Config(“news”, 200, 3)

///
for ((_, config) in uuidToConfigMapp) {
    Log.d("+++", "+++ config: ${config}”)
}

Log.e("+++", "+++ uuidToConfigMap.size ${uuidToConfigMap.size}")

val sortedUuidToConfigMap = uuidToConfigMap.toSortedMap<UUID, Config>(object: Comparator<UUID>{
    override fun compare(o1: UUID?, o2: UUID?): Int {
        val config1 = uuidToConfigMap[o1]
        val config2 = uuidToConfigMap[o2]

        Log.i("+++", "+++ $o1, $o2")

        if (config1 == null || config2 == null) {
            return -1
        }

        Log.d("+++", "+++ config: ${config1} <<<>>> ${config2}...")

        // sorted map iteration order will be in ascending order
        return (config1.priority - config2.priority)
    }
})

Log.e("+++", "+++ sortedUuidToConfigMap.size ${sortedUuidToConfigMap.size}")

for ((_, config) in sortedUuidToConfigMa) {

    Log.d("+++", "+++ config: ${config}")
}
///
```

The print out shows the result sortedUuidToConfigMa has only three entries (the entry

```
config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:yyy
```

is missing):

```
    +++ config: type:200, priority:3,  test:video
    +++ config: type:100, priority:2,  test:news
    +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:yyy
    +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:xxx
    +++ uuidToConfigMap.size 4

   +++ 657f1d4f-4f53-4f1f-83e4-3c624d12751f, 3a1a91da-5921-47f7-9104-c0efa48b6069
   +++ config: type:100, priority:2,  test:news <<<>>> type:200, priority:3,  test:video...
   +++ 600380fb-46a3-4cdd-9ce2-2806d6900420, 3a1a91da-5921-47f7-9104-c0efa48b6069
   +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:yyy <<<>>> type:200, priority:3,  test:video...
   +++ 600380fb-46a3-4cdd-9ce2-2806d6900420, 657f1d4f-4f53-4f1f-83e4-3c624d12751f
   +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:yyy <<<>>> type:100, priority:2,  test:news...
   +++ 77453616-ffff-4dd5-b525-8d5aebc89e92, 657f1d4f-4f53-4f1f-83e4-3c624d12751f
   +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:xxx <<<>>> type:100, priority:2,  test:news...
   +++ 77453616-ffff-4dd5-b525-8d5aebc89e92, 600380fb-46a3-4cdd-9ce2-2806d6900420
   +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:xxx <<<>>> type:1000, priority:1,  test:yyy…

   +++ sortedUuidToConfigMap.size 3
   +++ config: type:1000, priority:1,  test:xxx
   +++ config: type:100, priority:2,  test:news
   +++ config: type:200, priority:3,  test:video
```

Comment: You should test your comparator.

Comment: I think it returns ok,since if there's no second element to compare it returns a less element,try removing the `if (config1 == null || config2 == null) {
            return -1
        }` to check

Comment: why return -1 would cause one entry less, -1 just indicts the order, right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, thx, it is testing the comparator,  if these 4 entries have different 'priority' value it works fine, only when there are dup of the 'priority' value (like here two 1s) it will show the problem. do you see something wrong with the comparator?

Comment: it would appreciated if you could point out why you down vote this question, and it would be much better you could explain if you would know the answer an that could be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comparator, two `UUID`s are equal when stored priorities for them are equal. So `77453616-ffff-4dd5-b525-8d5aebc89e92` and `600380fb-46a3-4cdd-9ce2-2806d6900420` are considered equal and only one of them ends up in the result map.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is a great help! never thought the UUID as key but sort by a internal filed would get this result.

Comment: I guess it is misunderstand to how the hashMap.toSortedMa() works with the comparator, it is not like the way that the comparator is only controls the order in the sort process. but it also controls the result map entry (clearly in this case the key is not the same but the comparator says it is the same). lesson learned.

Comment: Yes, this is documented in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html.